# How to show list of web server files in HTML

Tags: html, file, web, webserver, directory-listing

I want to show list of all files from web server or a directory from web server into my WEB page using HTML. 
I searched google a lot but didn't find anything.
 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Possibility 1) activate DirectoryBrowsing [aka DirectoryListing] (Apache, IIS and probably all others support this).
Possibility 2) use PHP, JSP, ASP or whatever language to make a list of the files.

HTML itself is just a markup language, so there's no possibility to do that with HTML only.

Comment: +1 Yeah, for apache the term is [***Directory Listings***](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings)